# Qlikview - Freezing location of object while scrolling within the tab/ qvw document

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbscript, qlikview

Is there a Qlikview extension that allows the current selection box and search criteria (Both on top of the tabs) to be visible when we scroll down on any document? Something similar to the Top Row Freezing in Excel but doing it to objects instead.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default.

Long time ago i had similar "question" and i've ended writing a small document extension for this purpose.

Have a look at [this post](https://sstoichev.eu/2014/10/19/fixedcontent-qlikview-extension/) for detailed explanation and the [repo](https://github.com/countnazgul/Qlikview-Fixed-Content)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Stefan!!

Comment: Is it possible to omit the tab selector from the scrolling functionality?

Comment: I'm using modified version of [Tabrow Extension Templat](https://community.qlik.com/thread/97972) which modifies the tabs look and lock them as well